# Google test fixture : passing a class member size

Tags: c++, googletest

I managed to successfully set up google test on my little program and creature a fixture class. I try to test the size of a vector of integer "start_ind_id_array_" public member of my class Genealogy.
Here is the code :

```
class BuildgenTest : public ::testing::Test {   
protected:

    virtual void SetUp(){
    const string pedigree_fileName("../input_files/genealogies.txt");   
    const string start_filename("../input_files/start");
    Genealogy  curGen;
    curGen.ReadPedigree(pedigree_fileName.c_str());
    curGen.SetStartIndividual(start_filename.c_str());  

    cout << curGen.start_ind_id_array_.size() <<"\n" ;
    }
    Genealogy curGen;

};
TEST_F(BuildgenTest,veriftest){

    int number_of_starting_individuals = curGen.start_ind_id_array_.size();

    EXPECT_EQ(number_of_starting_individuals,3916);

}
```

The first cout gives me the number I expect, 3916. But then my test EXPECT_EQ fail because the size of my array is now 0, not my expected 3916.

Any idea what is causing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are shadowing curGen. You define it in setup function and in class body. The version in setup is shadowing the version in the body:

```
virtual void SetUp(){
const string pedigree_fileName("../input_files/genealogies.txt");   
const string start_filename("../input_files/start");

Genealogy  curGen;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

curGen.ReadPedigree(pedigree_fileName.c_str());
curGen.SetStartIndividual(start_filename.c_str());  

cout << curGen.start_ind_id_array_.size() <<"\n" ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I remove the version in the setup, and now it is working fine. I should have thought about that. Cheers.